# Cannot read property 'intercept' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, angular-http-interceptors

I have an interceptor which I want to provide in the app.module.ts as a const. So I used a separate file to declare all interceptors as an array of objects.

In http-interceptors/index.ts

```
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from "@angular/common/http";
import { ErrorIntercept } from "./error.interceptor";
import { CompanyInfoService } from "../services/companyInfo.service";

export const interceptorProviders = [
{ 'provide': HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, 'useclass': ErrorIntercept, 'multi': true, 'deps': [CompanyInfoService] }
];
```

In my app.module.ts,

```
import {interceptorProviders} from './http-interceptors/';
...
@NgModule ({
    ...
    providers: [interceptorProviders]
})
```

This throws the error - **Cannot read property 'intercept' of undefined**

However, when I directly provide the interceptor in the app.module.ts as below, it works as expected.

```
providers: [{
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: ErrorIntercept,
    multi: true,
    deps: [CompanyInfoService]
}]
```

I am not able to figure out the reason for this... so do let me know your thoughts. TIA!

Comment: try spreading your exported array

Answer (score 0):

You can spread the exported `interceptorProviders` array. Because the Providers expects an `object` or `class`. But you provided an array.

Also you need to change `useclass` to  `useClass`

```
export const interceptorProviders = [
  { 'provide': HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, 'useClass': ErrorIntercept, 'multi': true, 'deps': [CompanyInfoService] }
];
```

```
import {interceptorProviders} from './http-interceptors/';

@NgModule ({
   ...
   providers: [...interceptorProviders] // spread the array
})
```

Thanks to @alessandro

Comment: Hi, I tried this out, but am getting the error - Type '{ provide: InjectionToken<HttpInterceptor[]>; useclass: typeof ErrorIntercept; multi: boolean; deps: (typeof CompanyInfoService)[]; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Provider[]'.

Comment: edited the answer. `useClass` instead of `useclass`

Comment: The camel case update worked for me... I didnt have to use the spread operator though @SheikAlthaf

Comment: @Jeyashree.A Thats great to hear